# Postgres: Can't delete certain rows from table. Table not locked. Table not in transaction

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

I'm using postgres in DBeaver and, for some reason, there is a set of rows that cannot be deleted from a table. There is no transaction lock on the table. I've checked it with:

```
select * from pg_locks l join pg_class t on l.relation = t."oid" 
where t.relkind = 'r'
and t.relname = 'my_table'
```

and the returned table is empty.

When I run this query:

```
select * from my_table where cid = 383 and inserted_at is not null
```

It successfully returns a table containing 6 rows.

However when I run this query:

```
delete from my_table where cid = 383 and inserted_at is not null
```

The return statement says the query ran successfully with 0 rows updated.

Now, if I run this:

```
select * from my_table where cid = 383
```

I get a table with 10 rows (6 of which were included in the previous select statement).

And when I run

```
delete from my_table where cid = 383
```

The return statement says the query was run successfully with 4 rows updated; the same four rows that weren't a part of the original query. The 6 rows that weren't deleted before still remain.

The same thing happens when I use update statements instead of delete statements.

Comment: maybe there is a trigger involved behind scene?

Comment: YES! Thankyou! There was a no delete rule if a certain column was not null.